# Повторяющиеся запросы в React

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, react-hook

Начал знакомиться с React-Redux, axios, async ну и т.д. Помогите найти причину, по которой на сервер с клиента дублируются запросы в некоторых случаях.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я предполагал, одним из проблемных мест мог бы массив зависимостей в **useEffect**, но с ним вроде все в порядке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам файл, где происходит обращение к API:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала был один useEffect, потом разбил его на 2-а, но это не помогло. Пытался через react devtools найти причину, но пока не хватает понятия, куда и зачем следить. Приложение пока маленькое, поэтому прошу помочь разобраться с проблемой.

Comment: у вас включен [react strict mode](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

Comment: @xydope в проде этот режим не используется?

Comment: да, используется

Answer (score 0):

Во первых в массив зависимотей не надо пихать `dispatch`

Во вторых у вас оба `useEffect`-а сначала отрабатывают, когда компонента запускается, а во второй раз, когда менются переменные `productsLoaded` и `filtersLoaded`

Вам наверное надо убрать переменные из массива зависимостей, но оставить пустой массив, чтобы запросы были ровно 1 раз (но каждый раз), когда компонента будет загружена. Либо поставить туда другую переменную, которая будт меняться именно так как вам надо